# Is it a good practice to close dynamic shovel in RMQ?

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I am having a use case where I have to move msgs from dlq to queue. I have created dynamic shovels programmatically using python in a ECS container.

```
def shovel_messsages(self, source_queue, dest_queue, message_count):
    hostname = os.environ['HOSTNAME']
    vhost = os.environ['RABBIT_VHOST']
    headers = {'content-type':'application/json'}
    user_name = os.environ['RABBIT_USERNAME']
    milli_sec = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    shovel_name = 'test_{0}'.format(milli_sec)
    request_data = {
                "value":{
                   "src-protocol": "amqp091",
                    "src-uri": "amqp://"+user_name+"@/"+ vhost,
                    "src-queue":  source_queue,
                    "dest-protocol": "amqp091", "dest-uri": "amqp://"+user_name+"@/"+vhost,
                    "dest-queue": dest_queue,
                    "src-delete-after" : "queue-length"}
      }
    url = "http://{0}/api/parameters/shovel/{1}/{2}".format(hostname, vhost, shovel_name)
    response = requests.put(url=url, auth=(os.environ['RABBIT_USERNAME'],os.environ['RABBIT_PASSWORD']), data = json.dumps(request_data))
```

All this is working fine. Now my question is ,can leaving so many dynamic shovels open in production cause some kind of throttling or any such RMQ connection issues ? Is it a good practice to issue a DELETE shovel once the purpose is served. Any other better way of doing this ?

P.S - I am monitoring queues to check for incoming msgs to dlqs. So I have the option of running the above function on a set frequency throughout the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there can be two kind of dynamic shovels. One which doesn't get deleted automatically and the one which does.

The shovel created in the above post uses a property called `src-delete-after` which means that before a shovel is created, it kind of record the number of itmems in the source queue and then deleted itself once it's done transferring that many items.